# Azure Kudu is unable to restore packages after 2.2.1 sdk release

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, kudu

I'm having trouble to deploy to Azure App Service from git last 2 days. Kudu is unable to run dotnet restore with following error:

```
Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling ASP.NET Core Web Application deployment.
Restoring packages for D:\home\site\repository\Web.csproj...
D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk\2.2.100\NuGet.targets(114,5): error : Could not find file 'D:\home\.nuget\runtime.win7-x86.runtime.native.system.data.sqlclient.sni\4.0.1\runtime.win7-x86.runtime.native.system.data.sqlclient.sni.4.0.1.nupkg'. [D:\home\site\repository\Web.csproj]
Failed exitCode=1, command=dotnet restore "D:\home\site\repository\Web.csproj"
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
\r\nD:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\79.11121.3655\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
```

I tried to change SDK to 2.1.500 via global.json but the error is very same except SDK version.

Tried restart, stop/start the service with no luck. I couldn't find any way to deploy the app.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I am experiencing this too with the production version SDK 2.2.100. I cannot deploy to Azure. Everything was fine under 2.1

Comment: I created GitHub issue github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/2914. I was able to deploy the app with target framework 2.1 and Azure Tools extension in the Visual Studio Code. dotnet publish -c Relase, then right click bin/Release/netcoreapp2.1/publish folder and Deploy To Web App. SDK 2.2 seems to be broken on Azure now